# Code not extracting all products URLs on a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

My code below is meant to extract all the product urls on the page in the pages list. The site that i am scraping is a javascript site. My codes works perfectly on all other product category pages of the site.

However, on this page it only extracts 36 products which is the amount of products that is loaded onto the page. The pages variable is in a list as I've tried to extract the product urls by iterating over all the pages like this

```
pages = ['https://www.mrphome.com/en_za/shop/kitchen-dining/shop-dining/table-linen', 'https://www.mrphome.com/en_za/shop/kitchen-dining/shop-dining/table-linen?p=2-', 'https://www.mrphome.com/en_za/shop/kitchen-dining/shop-dining/table-linen?p=3-', 'https://www.mrphome.com/en_za/shop/kitchen-dining/shop-dining/table-linen?p=4-', 'https://www.mrphome.com/en_za/shop/kitchen-dining/shop-dining/table-linen?p=5-']
```

However if i run the code like this it still returns 36 items in the list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

baseurl = "https://www.mrphome.com/"

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"
}

produrlslug = []

pages = ['https://www.mrphome.com/en_za/shop/kitchen-dining/shop-dining/table-linen']
for page in pages:
    content = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.content, "lxml")
    url = soup.findAll('a', class_='product-image quickview-enabled')

for item in url:
    produrlslug.append(item['href'])
print(len(produrlslug))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indenting the second for loop which is iterating over `url` solves the problem.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

baseurl = "https://www.mrphome.com/"

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"
}

produrlslug = []

pages = ['https://www.mrphome.com/en_za/shop/kitchen-dining/shop-dining/table-linen']
for page in pages:
    content = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.content, "lxml")
    url = soup.findAll('a', class_='product-image quickview-enabled')
    # indentation missing
    for item in url:
        produrlslug.append(item['href'])
print(len(produrlslug))
```